# Calculate mean of consecutive repititions of values in pandas dataframe / numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe / numpy array:

```
a = np.array([ 55,  55,  69, 151, 151, 151, 103, 151, 151, 103])
df = pd.DataFrame([ 55,  55,  69, 151, 151, 151, 103, 151, 151, 103], columns = ["AOI"])
```

1. The values in this array can range from 1 to 151. I need to calculate the average consecutive repetition of the values. This involves the following logic:

- 55 occurs 2 time
- then 69 occurs 1 time
- then 151 occurs 3 times
- then 103 occurs 1 time
- then 151 occurs 2 times
- then 103 occurs 1 time.

2. So I have the following occurences for each value:

- 55: 2
- 69: 1
- 151: 3, 2
- 103: 1, 1

3. Now I need to calculate the mean of the occurences:

- 55: 2
- 69: 1
- 151: 2.5 ((3+2)/2)
- 103: 1 ((1+1)/2)

Ideally, in the end I have a numpy array with 151 entries. Each entry is zero and at index 55 I have the value 2, at index 69 the value 1, at index 151 the value 2.5 and at index 103 the value 1:

```
[0,0,0,0,...,2,0,0,...,1,0,0,0,...,1,0,0,0,....,2.5]
```

How can this be achieved? Unfortunately, I am not even able to perform step 1. A simple groupby and count the rows does not work, as I need the count of consecutive occurences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible solution using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```py
df['group'] = (df.AOI != df.AOI.shift()).cumsum()
x = df.groupby('group').agg({'AOI':('first', 'count')}).droplevel(0, axis=1)
x = x.groupby('first')['count'].mean()
x = x.reindex(range(0, x.index[-1] + 1), fill_value=0)

# print(x) <- if you want pd.Series
print(x.values) # print as numpy arrray
```

Prints:

```
[0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
 0.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.
 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.
 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  2.5]
```

Answer (score 2):

This line creates a set of groups for consecutive values:

```
df['consec_group'] = df['AOI'].ne(df['AOI'].shift()).cumsum()
```

(Nb `consec_group` values are `ids`. They do not have meaning as integers.) Then just group by both and take means:

```
>>> df.groupby(['AOI', 'consec_group'])['AOI'].count().unstack().mean(axis=1)
AOI
55     2.0
69     1.0
103    1.0
151    2.5
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Identify the consecutive values with either `shift` or `diff`, then double groupby, once for the count, once for the mean of the counts:

```
blocks = df['AOI'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()

output = blocks.groupby([df['AOI'],blocks]).size().groupby(level=0).mean()

print(out)
```

Output:

```
AOI
55     2.0
69     1.0
103    1.0
151    2.5
Name: AOI, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure numpy solution for completeness.

First identify the group lengths:

```
starts = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(a)) + 1]
lengths = np.diff(np.r_[starts, a.size])
```

The labels for each group are `a[starts]`, so you can compute the mean using unbuffered addition:

```
labels = a[starts]
n = a.max() + 1

counts = np.zeros(n)
np.add.at(counts, labels, 1)

sums = np.zeros(n)
np.add.at(sums, labels, lengths)

means = sums / counts
```